# How do I center my video inside the Circle?

Tags: react-native, styling

I want to Center my video in a React native app.

The video should be here

[image: hmmmmm.png]

in the middle of that circle.

I used `react-native-video`

My code is Looking thus

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import btnimage from '../../assets/images/button1.png';
import image from '../../assets/images/2.png';
//import AppVid from '../../assets/video/intro_xx1234vid.mp4';

import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';


const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const WalkThruPage2 = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const NavigateNextPage = () => {
    navigation.navigate('LandingPage');
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="stretch" style={styles.img} />
      <View >
        <Video
            source={{uri: 'https://mycoco.bsite.net/xx1234vid.mp4'}}
            style={{width: 30, height:30}}
            controls={true}
        />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          NavigateNextPage();
        }}
        style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 50, right: 30, zIndex: 1}}>
        <Image style={{height: 60, width: 60}} source={btnimage} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default WalkThruPage2;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  img: {
    height: screenHeight,
    width: screenWidth,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

But it does not show inside the Circle.

Please I would like to know how I should go about this.

Comment: You need to assign { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' } to the style property of the view class. Alternatively, you can apply { position: "absolute" } for the component with the **plus** and position it based on the dimensions of the parent component.